# How to properly generate a unique id and store it in a ConcurrentHashMap

Tags: java, concurrency, concurrenthashmap

I'm currently using a ConcurrentHashMap in which I store some files based on a unique id that I generate using `org.apache.commons.lang.RandomStringUtils#randomAlphanumeric`.

My current approach is this:

```
private ConcurrentHashMap <String, CustomFile> fileIdMap = 
                     new ConcurrentHashMap <String, SwitchConfigurationFile>();

public void importFile () {       
    CustomFile file = new CustomFile (generateFileID(), param1, param2, param3, param4);
    fileIdMap.put (file.getID(), file);       
}

private String generateFileID () {
   String generatedValue = RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(5);
   while (fileIdMap.containsKey(generatedValue)) {
       generatedValue = RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(5);
   }
   //I was thinking here to put the generated value into the Map
   //but at this moment I don't have the CustomFile instance
   //and null values are not allowed
   //maybe:
   //fileIdMap.put (generatedValue, new CustomFile());
   return generatedValue;
}
```

I was thinking: What if `fileIdMap.containsKey(generatedValue)` returns false and before I add it to the map another thread comes and adds the same key, I will have one CustomFile in the map instead of two. I know the chances are very small, but I want to take this into consideration.

So, what is the best approach in this situation and how can I ensure that I also have a unique id for each file?

Comment: Do you really need to generate the ID as a separate operation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [putIfAbsent(K key, V value)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#putIfAbsent-K-V-):

```
private String generateFileID () {
   CustomFile file = new CustomFile();
   String generatedValue = RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(5);
   while (fileIdMap.putIfAbsent(generatedValue, file) != null) {
       generatedValue = RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(5);
   }
   return generatedValue;
}
```

The implementation of this method in `ConcurrentHashMap` is correctly `synchronized` to avoid concurrence problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`#putIfAbsent()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#putIfAbsent(K,%20V)), which will atomically place the item in the map or return null otherwise, so you could put in your while loop while not null.
You will need to refactor your code a bit, since you don't yet have the `CustomFile` instance.
One thing you could do is place a dummy item in first, then replace it with your real object once it is created, but this might cause another synchronization issues if other threads read that object in the mean time.